# Cannot install anaconda in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I tried installing anaconda on the Raspberry Pi using the 32 bit installer in their webpage. After finding out where the file is located I put the command

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86.sh
```

Once the installation location was picked, I got the following error.

```
installing: python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1 ...
/home/pi/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86.sh: line 373: /home/pi/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Any idea how to install anaconda?

Comment: You may find the following post will answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you try to install Anaconda for x86 CPUs (such as Intels) whereas the Raspberry Pi has an ARM based CPU. You need to use the following install script:

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
```

Comment: I tried many times but after the third line and after wrote 'yes' it shows a bunch of  'y' after that nothing. I cannot write anything.

Comment: The file `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh` seems to be from 2015...so unfortunately not really up to date.

Comment: @tkazik My answer is 3 years old. As far as I am aware, there is no newer version. Maybe try https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

Answer (score 0):

You may check the file permissions such
`sudo chmod 775 Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86.sh`

Alternatively you may just run with `./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86.sh`